# Using require/require_once() in a functions file

Tags: php

my functions.php file is just a placeholder for many different functions. I have another file settings.php that I use to store different settings. Some of the functions in functions.php will need to access some of the variables in settings.php, so I tried:

```
require("settings.php")
```

on top of the functions.php file, but that does not seem to give my functions access to the variable in settings.php. I need to put require("settings.php") in every function separately.

Is there a way I can declare the variables in settings.php to be accessible globally to all functions defined in functions.php?

Thank you,

Comment: what you're saying should work fine. can you post an example? do you understand variable scope?

Comment: You want to define a single `$config[]` array with all the settings variables. This way you avoid aliasing each after another with `global`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your functions in `functions.php` to use global variables defined in `settings.php`.

Inside `settings.php`;

```
$var1 = "something";
$var2 = "something else";
```

By using the `global` keyword:

```
function funcName() {
  global $var1;
  global $var2;

 // Rest of the function...
}
```

Or more preferably, using the `$GLOBALS[]` superglobal array. Any variables declared at global scope, like I assume your settings.php vars are, will be included as array keys in `$GLOBALS[]`.  It's a little better for readability than using the `global` keyword inside each function.

```
function funcName() {
  $y = $GLOBALS['var1'];
  $x = $GLOBALS['var2'];
 // Etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although you've set these variables in your `settings.php` file, when you try to reference them in your functions it won't work. This is because variables in functions a locally scoped to the function.

To access these global variables you need to use the `global` keyword to bring your *global* variables into scope.

For example:

```
// Declared in settings.php
$x = 1234;


// One of your functions
function MyFunc()
{
  global $x;

  DoSomething($x);
}
```

You need to do this for every function where `$x` is accessed.

For more information see:

> [Variable scope - php.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the details of your issue, but you may wish to use `require_once()` within each function. This seems to be better idea than using some global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking global variables.

However that's not the best way to go.

Can you perhaps create a class?

```
class SomeClass
{
    private $settings;

    function __construct()
    {
        require_once($settings);
        $this->settings = $variable(s) from settings file
    }

    function some_function()
    {
        print($this->settings['something']);
    }
}
```